# What are all the wavelengths of the dueterium spectra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen, elements

What are all the wavelengths in the spectrum of deuterium?

I've searched and came up with an abstract that only lists the visible part of deuterium's spectrum (see http://myslu.stlawu.edu/~jmil/physics/legacy/student_projects/2001/fiacco.shtml for details). If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: I think this question would be a little better for the site if you edit it to ask "what are all the wavelengths in the deuterium spectrum?" and include a bit of information about where you've already looked. People will still give you references as needed.

Comment: Thanks! And actually one thing I forgot to mention (sorry about that): it's best to restate the question in the body of the post itself. I'll made a quick edit that does that for you, but feel free to change it again if you like.